# Spring Webflux with Spring MVC - nulls emitted when using doOnEach

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm experimenting a bit with Spring Webflux and Spring MVC, and encountered an interesting case.

Starting with a simple controller:

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<String> list(final Model model) {
    Flux<User> users = this.userRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    return Mono.just("users/list");
}
```

The `userReposutory` is a custom `ConcurrentHashMap`-based implementation. Here you can find the `findAll` method:

```
@Override
public Flux<User> findAll() {
    return Flux.fromIterable(this.users.values());
}
```

Whenever I try to return to access the "users/list" view, everything seems to be working properly.

But, if I try to rewrite the controller using an idiomatic reactive approach, problems start appearing:

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<String> list(final Model model) {
    return this.userRepository.findAll()
      .collectList()
      .doOnEach(users -> model.addAttribute("users", users.get()))
      .map(u -> "users/list");
}
```

If I hit the endpoint, I'm getting this in logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ConcurrentModel does not support null attribute value
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193)
    at org.springframework.ui.ConcurrentModel.addAttribute(ConcurrentModel.java:75)
    at org.springframework.ui.ConcurrentModel.addAttribute(ConcurrentModel.java:39)
    at com.baeldung.lss.web.controller.UserController.lambda$list$0(UserController.java:37)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:132)
```

Apparently, some stray `null` is making its way there. Let's filter out all of them eagerly then:

```
@RequestMapping
public Mono<String> list(final Model model) {
    return this.userRepository.findAll()
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collectList()
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .doOnEach(users -> model.addAttribute("users", users.get()))
      .map(u -> "users/list");
}
```

Same problem, but... if I squeeze everything in a `map()` call, everything works again:

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<String> list(final Model model) {
    return this.userRepository.findAll()
      .collectList()
      .map(users -> {
          model.addAttribute("users", users);
          return "users/list";
      });
}
```

Although, placing side-effects in `map` is not optimal.

Any ideas what's wrong with the `doOnEach()` here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very nice question. Let's see what the [JavaDocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) tell about `doOnEach`:

> `public final Mono<T> doOnEach(Consumer<? super Signal<T>>
>   signalConsumer)`
>
> Add behavior triggered when the Mono emits an item,
>   fails with an error or completes successfully. All these events are
>   represented as a `Signal` that is passed to the side-effect callback

Curious. The `users` in `doOnEach(users -> ...)` is not an `List<User>` but a `Signal<List<User>>`. This `Signal<T>` object won't be null, which explains why the `filter` methods in the second version don't work.

The [JavaDocs for `Signal<T>`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Signal.html#get--) says that the `get()` method is explicitly marked as `@Nullable` and will return a non-null value only on next item arrives. If the completion or error signal is generated, then it will return `null`.

**Solutions:**

1. Use `doOnNext` instead: You are interested in the next value, not any signal that comes from the source stream.
2. Do a null-check in `doOnEach` lambda: This will work too, but since you're not interested in other events, is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, I come from the RxJava world and I didn't realize that there's `doOnNext` next to `doOnEach`! :)

Comment: yeah, the 2 are pretty close conceptually, `doOnEach` is `doOnNext` + `doOnComplete` + `doOnError` rolled into one. RxJava2 has the same naming convention btw.